# Multiple view in same page asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to render two seperate views in same page. I mean, for example I am showing details of a shop, I need to get the Category List (View1- Action results  returns all catogories in that shop) and BrandList (View2 - Action results   returns exclusive brands in that shop). How can I achieve this? or how can I write my controller class to get this?
Thanks in advance.
..Throjen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are Partial Views

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/638_Understanding_Partial_Views_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Application.aspx

Comment: After reading that article I got few doubts. There we are getting the view data from   public ActionResult List(). My doubt is how this will be called? No where mentioned like List() should be called.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. I was thinking like stupid.. in traditional way. many thanks to ur time spent for answering me... Throjen

Comment: no problem man, one does need to start thinking in a different way when using MVC. takes a while to get used to :)